# I just want to get "value" in json document. (in Spring-boot)

Tags: json, spring-boot, key

I am sending this as body from postman : "userId":"11" .

```
 @PostMapping(value="/logout",consumes = "application/json")
  public void logout(@RequestBody String userId){
   ordersService.logout(userId);
}
```

Then return holds userId= "{\r\n "userId":"11"\r\n}" ,but i just want to get the value 11.I dont want to get the key. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```
    @RequestMapping(
       path = "/logout",
       method = RequestMethod.PUT,
       produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
    )
    public void logout(@NotNull @RequestBody Long userId)
    {
        ordersService.logout(userId);
    }
```

Comment: @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, path = "/logout", consumes = "application/json")
    public void logout(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) {
        ordersService.logout(payload.get("userId").toString());
    }

Comment: I am getting an error like: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING.

Comment: what should I do?